# Moderncv: How to avoid bold lettering for recipients?

Tags: formatting, moderncv

I'm using `moderncv` to get my cover letter. In the upper part of the document LaTeX sets up the address line of the company. The thing is that the first part of this address line has bold letters. However, I'd like to have everything without bold letters.

### Details

The crucial command is the first `{}` of the recipients-line (see MWE). The first `{}` makes the text bold. I'd like to leave the first `{}` free to avoid bold lettering. However, LaTeX will output me an error if I do so. Do you have any idea how to solve this.

Many thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}   

\moderncvtheme[black]{banking}

\usepackage[scale=0.75, top=20mm, bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} %notwendig für eingescannte Unterschrift.
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %notwendig für die Darstellung des Datums in deutscher Weise.



\makeatletter


\newcommand*{\birthdate}[1]{\def\@birthdate{#1}}
\newcommand*{\civilstatus}[1]{\def\@civilstatus{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{34}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2!60}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
%
\newlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{0pt}% dummy value
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  \def\socialsdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
    \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  % optional detailed information box
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@birthdate}}{}{\makenewline{\@birthdate}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@civilstatus}}{}{\makenewline{\@civilstatus}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile}%
      %\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\makenewline\phonesymbol\@phone}%
      %\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\faxsymbol\@fax}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % detailed information
  \llap{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle

%------------------

\makeatother

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Title}                                                                                                      
\birthdate{Birthday}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}

\begin{document}


%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company}{Street\\ City}
\date{\today}

\opening{To who it may concern:}
\closing{Kind regards,}

\makelettertitle

%------------------------------

Hello



%----------Schlussformel-------

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @Phil: Please shorten your LaTeX code to a [MWE (minimal working example)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/25077).

Answer (score 4):

You can simply write

```
\recipient{\mdseries Company}{Street\\ City}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[black]{banking}

\usepackage[scale=0.75, top=20mm, bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} %notwendig für eingescannte Unterschrift.
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %notwendig für die Darstellung des Datums in deutscher Weise.



\makeatletter


\newcommand*{\birthdate}[1]{\def\@birthdate{#1}}
\newcommand*{\civilstatus}[1]{\def\@civilstatus{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{34}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2!60}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
%
\newlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{0pt}% dummy value
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  \def\socialsdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
    \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  % optional detailed information box
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@birthdate}}{}{\makenewline{\@birthdate}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@civilstatus}}{}{\makenewline{\@civilstatus}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile}%
      %\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\makenewline\phonesymbol\@phone}%
      %\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\faxsymbol\@fax}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % detailed information
  \llap{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle

%------------------

\makeatother

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Title}
\birthdate{Birthday}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}

\begin{document}


%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{\mdseries Company}{Street\\ City}
\date{\today}

\opening{To who it may concern:}
\closing{Kind regards,}

\makelettertitle

%------------------------------

Hello



%----------Schlussformel-------

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Phil You're welcome. Remember that you can accept the answer that helped you most to mark the question as solved. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in your preamble (say  before `\begin{document}`)

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\makelettertitle}{\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}{\upshape\@recipientname}{}{}
\makeatother
```

and use

```
\recipient{Company}{Street\\ City}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[black]{banking}

\usepackage[scale=0.75, top=20mm, bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} %notwendig für eingescannte Unterschrift.
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %notwendig für die Darstellung des Datums in deutscher Weise.



\makeatletter


\newcommand*{\birthdate}[1]{\def\@birthdate{#1}}
\newcommand*{\civilstatus}[1]{\def\@civilstatus{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{34}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2!60}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
%
\newlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{0pt}% dummy value
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  \def\socialsdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
    \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  % optional detailed information box
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@birthdate}}{}{\makenewline{\@birthdate}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@civilstatus}}{}{\makenewline{\@civilstatus}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile}%
      %\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\makenewline\phonesymbol\@phone}%
      %\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\faxsymbol\@fax}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % detailed information
  \llap{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle

%------------------

\makeatother

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Title}
\birthdate{Birthday}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\makelettertitle}{\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}{\upshape\@recipientname}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company}{Street\\ City}
\date{\today}

\opening{To who it may concern:}
\closing{Kind regards,}

\makelettertitle

%------------------------------

Hello



%----------Schlussformel-------

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

[image]